# why Lsimodel from Gensim show different output while taking the same input?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lsa

I am doing a natural language process project, when I try to use gensim'API to get LSI similarity matrix, every time I run my code, the LSImodel gives me a different similarity matrix. they are not totally different, but slightly different, like last time one of the number is -0.42562, but it change to -0.42116 next time I run my code. It makes my rest analysis change totally.

```
Lsi = gensim.models.LsiModel
lsimodel = Lsi(corpus_tfidf, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=20)
lsi_similarity = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsimodel[corpus_tfidf])
```

I have checked that my input corpus_tfidf and dictionary is the same every time. why would this happen? is there some solution for it?

Comment: Many such algorithms either explicitly use randomization (especially during initialization), or can be affected by the random influences of things like a slightly-different multithreaded operations. Typically such fluctuations/jitter don't change the overall quality of the final model, just the exact numbers/weights/values. In what way has this jitter made your later analysis "change totally"? (If you get "good" results from one lucky run, & bad results from another, that could be a sign some other data/parameter is insufficient for stable results.)

Comment: @gojomo, thank you so much. So this kind of fluctuation is inevitable, isn't it? Most of my final results are as expected, but I didn't know it was random before, I didn't save my model, I can't repeat my first analysis progress right now. guess I have to save the new model for future work.

Comment: Yes, saving the model if you want to perfectly match results is a good idea, especially if the training is time/resource consuming. But as per above: the contrast between multiple models can be a useful signal of process quality. If their outputs are about-as-equally-useful, even though the fine details/exact-numbers jitter, that's good. If the jitter from one run to the next makes a big quality difference, the process is likely weaker-than-it-should-be.